# Sending an integer to COM1 using SerialPort

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I'm having difficulty sending an integer to a serial port... I'm trying stuff like this, which run fine but I'm not picking anything up at the port.

```
Private Sub fireToPort()
    Dim sPort As New SerialPort("COM1", 56000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
    sPort.Open()
    sPort.Write(New Byte() {Hex(1), 255}, 0, 0)
    sPort.Close()
End Sub
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't the last argument to sPort.Write be the number of bytes you want to send?

e.g.

```
  sPort.Write(New Byte() {Hex(1), 255}, 0, 2)
```

Comment: LOL. Good point: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Yup.  Baudrate is wrong too, 57600 is the closest match unless the driver can handle it somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Get hold of [PortMon By Mark Russinovich (formerly of SysInternals)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx).

This will help you confirm that the port is being opened, configured correctly and written to.
You should see your process making an `IRP_MJ_WRITE` operation with a result of `SUCCESS`.

If that is all working then the issue is probably that whatever you have attached to COM1 is expecting a different baud rate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    'I looped my serial port on COM5
    Dim sPort As New IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM5", 57600, IO.Ports.Parity.None, _
                                         8, IO.Ports.StopBits.One)

    sPort.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None '<<< pick the correct one

    sPort.Open()
    Dim b() As Byte = New Byte() {1, 255, 0, 0}
    sPort.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
    sPort.BaseStream.Flush()

    'because I looped the port I should be able to read it
    Dim b1(3) As Byte
    sPort.Read(b1, 0, 4)
    sPort.Close()
```

Comment: No problem.  My breakout box is the oldest piece of equipment (20+ years) that I have and still works.

Answer (score 1):

```
sPort.Write(New Byte() {Hex(1), 255}, 0, 0)
```

The last argument is supposed to be `255` which is the length of data that you will send.